# How is the performance of a virtual hard disk (in Virtual Box) formatted in HFS+?

Tags: mac, virtualbox, hfs+

i would like to 'test' a virtualized Mac in Virtual Box. I'm wondering: can i create a virtual hard disk (in VirtualBox) then format it in HFS+ (native for Mac) ? 
Are there any known issues or problemed ? 
Thanks

Comment: What could possibly go wrong with your **virtual machine** that you need to make sure of it in advance?

Comment: What tool do you want to use to format the VHD? Which OS do you use to host VirtualBox and what version of OS X do you want to "test"?

Comment: I would like to use OsX Lion, and format the partition using Lion standard tool to format disk.

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/q/360517/83694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience (Snow Leopard only) HFS+ works just fine inside VirtualBox.