# Which disk image support siplit into files, VDI, VMDK, or VHD?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualization, vhd, vdi, vmdk

Different from this quesiton,
[What disk image should I use with VirtualBox, VDI, VMDK, VHD or HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/360517/what-disk-image-should-i-use-with-virtualbox-vdi-vmdk-vhd-or-hdd)

1. Does only vmdk format support 'splitting the storage file into files'? What about other formats?
2. For supporting format, is its specification or implementation Open Source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, only VMDK supports splitting. It is proprietary.

There is a limited workaround: With Microsoft Windows and Linux versions that do support spanned volumes, you can create multiple virtual hard disks and have the operating system span a logical volume across them.

The limitation of this workaround is lies in the operating system's limitation of the number of hard disks that a logical volume can span.